# The area of a right triangle is $2 \sqrt{3}$. Determine its height projected to the hypotenuse if it divides the right angle in a ratio of 1:2.

Tags: geometry, triangles

> The area of a right triangle is equal to $2 \sqrt{3}$. Determine its height projected to the hypotenuse if it divides the right angle in a ratio of 1:2.

I don't really understand how to obtain the height projected to the hypotenuse here. I've tried using the formulas $S = \frac12ab$ and $S= \frac12ch_c$ where a and b are the legs, c is the hypotenuse and $h_c$ is the height projected to the hypotenuse. Answer given is $\sqrt3$.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The altitude to the hypotenuse of a right triangle divides the triangle into two similar copies of itself.  So knowing that the altitude divides the right angle in the ratio $1:2$, we conclude that the right triangle's acute angles are $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$.

Let $x$ and $x\sqrt3$ represent the lengths of the legs of the right triangle.  We know that the area of the triangle is $\frac12\cdot x\cdot x\sqrt 3=2\sqrt3$, so $\frac12 x^2=2$ and thus $x=2$.  The hypotenuse of the triangle is therefore $4$ and the height to the hypotenuse is given by $\frac12\cdot 4\cdot h=2\sqrt 3$ or $h=\sqrt3$.

Comment: Ok. I understand the concept here. But why did you let x and x sqrt(3) to represent the legs of the triangle?

Comment: @ThermalRaindrops62 Because it is a $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ right triangle, we know that the sides are in the proportion $1:\sqrt3:2$.

Comment: Oh ok got it now. Tq.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$S = h \cdot (a + b) / 2$$
$$h^2 = a \cdot b$$
$$h = a\sqrt{3}$$

Then

$$b = 3a$$
$$S = 2a^2\sqrt{3} = 2\sqrt{3}$$
$$a = 1$$
$$h = \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: hmm.. why did you let b = 3a here when the ratio is 1:2?

Comment: all triangles are similar and in all angles are 30, 60 and 90 degrees, so legs are $\sqrt{3} : 1$, therefore since $\frac{h}{a} = \frac{b}{h} = \sqrt{3}$, then b = 3a

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand how you get √3

Comment: because right angle is divided with ratio 1:2, so angles are 30 and 60 degrees. In such triangles hypotenuse ratio to smaller leg is 2:1, so the other leg is $\sqrt{3}$